# GatsbyJS & Netlify forms custom subject for form email notifications

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, gatsby, netlify

I've created a Netlify form on my GatsbyJS site. The form itself works just fine. However, I am having issues changing the subject of my form. I have followed the instructions found in the [Netlify forms documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/forms/notifications/#email-notifications). In the documentation it states:

*"[...] add a subject field to your form, and the value of that field will be used for the notification email subject. This field does not need to be visible to your users."*

I am using a hidden subject field with the value of my subject in order to set subject of my form:

`<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="My subject" />`

I am receiving submission from the form but the subject is not taking effect. Any clues on what I am missing ??

After doing some research I found a error in my code:

`Failed form propType: You provided a value prop to a form field without an onChange handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use defaultValue. Otherwise, set either onChange or readOnly.`

so I changed `value` to be `defaultValue` instead:

`<input type="hidden" name="subject" defaultValue="My subject" />`

However, this doesn't seem to solve my issue. Same result as before: I am receiving the form, but subject doesn't seem to take effect.

Been going through Netlify forms [debugging guide](https://community.netlify.com/t/support-guide-debugging-netlify-site-builds/142), but haven't been able to find anything that solves issue. Also tried using HTML to React parser but that didn't do anything either.

The form itselves I am using:

```
 <form
              name="contact"
              method="POST"
              data-netlify="true"
              className="hero-form"
              data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
            >
              <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
              <input type="hidden" name="bot-field" />
              <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="My subject" />
              <p>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Dit navn" />
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Din email" />
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Dit tlf. nr." />
              </p>
              <p>
                <textarea
                  name="message"
                  placeholder="Skriv evt. hvad det handler om"
                  rows="5"
                ></textarea>
              </p>
              <p>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
              </p>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the subject of emails by including a `subject` field.

HTML:

```
<form
...
   data-netlify="true"
   data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
>
...
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Subject to be replaced..."/>
...
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
 fetch('/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { ‘Content-Type’: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: encode({
    'form-name': form.getAttribute('name'),
    'subject': 'New message',
    …dataForm,
    }),
 })
```

Reference: https://community.netlify.com/t/custom-subject-on-forms-not-working/13564